# Is there a way to export a sonar project as a doc or pdf?

Tags: sonarqube

I want to save my sonar project as a doc or a pdf document instead of the web app interface, is it possible ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two available plugins that allow you to see metrics in PDF format 
http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/PDF+Plugin (Community plugin)

For Sonar 5.6 LTS => http://www.sonarsource.com/2016/06/13/sonarqube-governance-1-0-released/ (Plugin provided by SonarSource)

Comment: The community plugin link is broken. You can find it there : [Sonar PDF Report Plugin](https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-pdf-report)

Comment: And there, the links to codehaus etc are broken - this project seems dead?

Comment: It seems so. The project hasn't been updated for years so I would consider it `legacy` :)